# Parse linked dataframes into json

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to parse these dataframes:

```
Master:

     Name   String            Column_1            Column_2
0  Name_1  Value_1  Name_Other_Table_1  Name_Other_Table_2
1  Name_2  Value_2  Name_Other_Table_1  Name_Other_Table_2

Name_Other_Table_1:

     Name Sub_Columumn_1        Sub_Column_2
0  Name_1      Value_1_1  Name_Other_Table_3
1  Name_1      Value_1_2  Name_Other_Table_3
2  Name_2      Value_2_1  Name_Other_Table_3
3  Name_2      Value_2_2  Name_Other_Table_3

Name_Other_Table_2:

     Name Sub_Column_3
0  Name_1            A
1  Name_1            Z
2  Name_2            Z

Name_Other_Table_3

     Name Sub_Column_1 Sub_SubString
0  Name_1    Value_1_1             A
1  Name_1    Value_1_2             B
```

Into a json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Name_1",
    "String" : "Value_1",
    "Column_1": [
      {
        "Sub_Columumn_1": "Value_1_1",
        "Sub_Sub_Column_1": [
          {
            "Sub_SubString": "A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Sub_Columumn_1": "Value_1_2",
        "Sub_Sub_Column_1": [
          {
            "Sub_SubString": "B"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Column_2":[
      {
        "Sub_Column_3": "A"
      },
      {
        "Sub_Column_3": "Z"
      }
    ]
  },...
```

A way to rephrase the question would be how do I get a hierarchical data structure out of a series of 'linked' tables?

Originally this comes from an excel file and tables are linked via the name of the sheets.